# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). lost connection

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing, file-permissions, user-permissions, public-key

when I want to transfer files from my local computer to the server with the following command:

`scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa /home/user/file user@extension:/home/user/`

`Warning: Identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). lost connection`
`
the file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa exists, I don't know why it doesn't recognize it

I have made some permission changes using chmod and have had no results. I'm frustrated

I show the command `-ssh user` so they can see any possible errors

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to escuela.hpc.cedia.edu.ec [201.159.221.23] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_private_type: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_private_cert: Permission denied
debug1: key_load_private_cert: Permission denied
debug1: key_load_private_cert: Permission denied
debug1: key_load_private_cert: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_private_type: Permission denied
debug1: key_load_private_type: Permission denied
debug1: key_load_private_type: Permission denied
debug1: key_load_private_type: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_cert: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_cert: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_cert: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_cert: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Authenticating to escuela.hpc.cedia.edu.ec:22 as 'jean.ramos'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:TPXt0x27CHY0aWFqRiznAgVYDlx9y2N2+Xj0wYo6iMk
debug1: Host 'escuela.hpc.cedia.edu.ec' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1014)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1014)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jean.ramos/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`
```